# My Excel scatter chart will not read in all of my data?

Tags: excel

I have 100s of lines of data here is a sample of the first two lines:

| Manufacturer | Price | Increase |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Volvo | 100k | 3% |
| Audi | 150k | 6% |

I want to create a scatter plot with Price on the X axis and Increase on the Y axis whilst being able to use a filter to filter by manufacturer.

When I highlight the data to create a Scatter Chart, it does not read in the Manufacturer nor allow me to filter.  If I format as table first, it still does not allow me.

Does anyone have any idea what the issue is.

Comment: Can you show an example of the issue and of your desired output?

Comment: This would be a question for SuperUser, not Stack Overflow (it's unrelated to programming).